# Django Soft Delete

Tags: python, django

Since django's default user model uses is_active as the flag for soft deletes, does it make sense to name the field is_active for every other model that needs to be soft deleted?

is_deleted seems to be far more common, but it seems like is_active keeps things consistent, which is better, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's really more of your preference. For consistency's sake, `is_active` is better. There might be some cases where `is_deleted` might make more sense/feel more natural to the developer. For what it's worth, we had both fields `is_active` and `is_deleted` in one of our projects. We used `is_deleted` to denote soft deletes and `is_active` to mean whether or not that model could still actively participate/engage with the system.